# Is there any point of using CDI @Named CDI without any value?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

Is there any point of using CDI @Named without a value? Isn't it then simply equivalent of using @Qualifier and @Default together?

```
@Named
public class GifFileEditor implements ImageFileEditor {
```

Comment: Cdi did not exist in javaee-5

Answer (score 3):

If I remember right, `@Named` with no `value` element value, when applied to a managed bean, does three things:

1. It applies the `@Named` qualifier with an effective `value` of the simple class name.
2. It sets the `beanName` of the bean in question to the simple class name.
3. It (is the one qualifier that) does not cause the implicit `@Default` qualifier to be removed.

Now, if you apply it programmatically using, for example, `BeanConfigurator#addBean`, then *you* are in charge of deciding which of these behaviors to implement yourself.

Comment: Class name in with lower case first letter (or even a little more complex logic)